# Photoshop CC 2020: How can I save as EXR using Exr-IO?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-format, save, image-format, plugin

I just downloaded and installed Exr-IO. I can easily open an EXR with it, but I can't figure out how to **save** as EXR. Apologies if this is a really simple question, but I've been googling for about an hour and can't seem to find any relevant information.

[This is from Exr-IO's documentation](https://www.exr-io.com/writing-openexr-files/) but it doesn't cover how to actually export the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out what my problem was. I was in grayscale mode. In order for OpenEXR export options to appear, you need to be in RGB Color mode (and 32 bit). Maybe this will help someone down the line.

Comment: How did you get Exr-Io to work in 2020 (v22)? How did you disabled the integrated EXR Plug-In

Comment: To add to this answer, I also found I had to merge all layers before the OpenEXR option was available at export.